# Hide tab from JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm using Netbeans gui to create a simple app.

This is my structure (the layout is **free design** ):

[image]

Basically I have 3 tabs and want to hide one of them (the select one in the image) based on a condition. Something like if the user as some privileges show that tab, otherwise don't show that tab.

On my code I've tried;

```
 if (userRole == 1){
    pnlAdiconarSala.setVisible(false);
 }
```

but this tab is always showing.

With my implementation, can I hide the tab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an clean example

1. [**How to Use Tabbed Panes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#tabapi)
2. [**Inserting, Removing, Finding, and Selecting Tabs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#tabapi)

Comment: @Favolas what is the simple solution to hide and un-hide a tab?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```
if (userRole == 1){
   tbpGeral.remove(pnlAdiconarSala)
}
```